# How to allow ESXi read-only user to login?

Tags: authentication, readonly, esxi

As per my understanding access.conf file specifies (user/group, host), (user/group) or (user/group, tty) combinations for which a login will be either accepted or refused.
In case of ESXi server, only Administrator is allowed to login.                                 As the entry for Administrator in access.conf file is like : "+:Administrator:All"
But, for all other roles it does not allow login as they has entry in the file like : "-:username:All".

Answer (score 0):

To login through that users. You will need to set the password for those users. To set the password please follow the below steps

## Through the Vsphere Client

Open the Esxi in Vsphere client with Admin privilege

Then in left side click on the "Host Name/IP" Then in the right select the "Local Users & Groups"

Right click on the user and choose Edit option you will get a window to edit the user credentials. There you can give your new password for the user and then you can login with that particular user

## Through the linux shell

Type the below command in your linux shell window

passwd username

Then it will ask for the password. Give your new password. After completing this step you can login with that user.